# Same Spring bean instance for both ear and war deployed in Wildly

Tags: java, spring, wildfly

I've deployed an ear and war toghether in my Wildfly 10 instance so I've noticed that they sharing the same singleton bean instance but I need to start it in different instance to use in respective scenarios.

Debugging in eclipse I have detected the same instance id during execution

How can I solve?

thanks in advance

Comment: Are your Spring Framework jars installed as WildFly modules or have they been added to the respective EAR and WAR modules?

Comment: Thanks for reply @SteveC I'm deploying 1 Ear and 1 War, both deployments need to instantiate a bean importing the same application context as import resource from a common jar as maven dependency. The goal is to isolate application context for each deployed archives thanks again

Comment: Where is the common jar deployed? Do the WAR and EAR each have their own copy of it?

Comment: Yes @SteveC :-(

Comment: It is not possible that they are the same instance as they have been created in different class loaders.

Comment: @SteveC I think so too but accesing to a property from that class I get the same value for both instance but I set different value in each application context es: suffix=ear and suffix=war but I always get ear

Comment: I think so too but using these beans in both deployed archives they have the same value for one of property I eill provide a sample scenario to clearify my issue thanls a lot @SteveC

Answer (score 0):

In your spring configuration file set the target bean "scope" attribute  to "prototype"

Comment: thanks for reply @yohannes I've already tried with prototype scope but nothing is changed  it seems that they share beans within application server...